# Compute the Probability that a hand of 3 cards will contain a king and an ace of the same suit

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

This is a problem for my Homework and I see Inclusion-Exclusion method but I still cannot understand it. Can someone please help me. Thanks

**EDIT:**

I tried doing it this way, and I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it

(13C2 * 39C1)/52C3

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: As a suggestion, I wouldn't have thought that Inclusion-Exclusion was the easiest path here.  How many same suited $KQ$ pairs are there?  How many winning hands are there?  How many hands are there in total?

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well to blank statements of homework problems.  We're not here to do your homework for you.  We'll gladly meet you half way if you show some effort though.  What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  I gave you a strong hint in my prior comment...can you get anywhere with that?

Comment: @lulu this is the way that I did it

Comment: Where did you get that numerator?  I agree that $\binom {52}3$ is the total number of three card hands.

Comment: 13C2 would be the part where i would take 2 from 13 cards of same suit and 39C1 would be the part where I take 1 from the rest

Comment: The problem doesn't ask you to choose two cards of the same suit, it asks you to choose the King and Ace from a single suit (Note:  in my first comment I wrote $Q$ where I should have written $A$).  Nor does the problem tell you that the third card must be of a different suit.

Comment: So, again:  How many same suited $KA$ pairs are there?

Comment: there are only 4

Comment: Exactly.  And having chosen one of those four pairs, how many possible "third cards" are there?

Comment: there would be 44 cards to choose from

Comment: No....try again.  Say I choose $K\spadesuit,\, A\spadesuit$.  How many cards are available for a third choice?

Comment: ohhh there would still be 50 cards to choose from if that is the case

Comment: Exactly.  And as there are $4$ choices for the $KA$ pair, that means that the total number of winning hands is....

Comment: is it 4C1 x 50C1?

Comment: It is, good!  Worth noting:  at this stage you need to check that you aren't double counting, but that's clear here.  If you have the spade $KA$ pair then you can't have the diamond $KA$ pair, say.  But if you were looking at four card hands, then $K\spadesuit, A\spadesuit, K\diamondsuit, A\diamondsuit$ is possible, for example, and you'd have to subtract off the duplicates.  Not a problem here.  So...do you have the full answer now?

Comment: As an exercise, I suggest doing the four card version.  The same concept works for the calculation but, as I said, it's a little harder to count the winning hands because the naive approach has a little double counting.  Good practice!

Comment: So it's just adding the 52C3 as denominator right?

Comment: Yes, that's all that's left.

Comment: thank you lulu for helping. I really appreciate taking the time to tutor me on this one

Answer (score 1):

First thought: by drawing $3$ cards it cannot happen that of two different suits a king and an ace are drawn. So it is enough to find out the probability that this happens for suit diamonds and to multiply the result by $4$ on base of mutually exclusiveness and symmetry.

So draw $3$ cards and let $D$ denote the event that king and ace of diamonds are selected.

Let $E_i$ denote the event that the $i$-th card drawn is the king or the ace of diamonds.

Then $D=(E_1\cap E_2)\cup(E_1\cup E_3)\cup(E_2\cup E_3)$ is a union of $3$ equiprobable and mutually exclusive events so that:

$$P(D)=3\times P(E_1\cap E_2)=3\times P(E_1)P(E_2\mid E_1)=3\times\frac2{52}\frac1{51}$$

This leads to: $$P(\text{king and ace of same suite are selected})=4\times3\times\frac2{52}\frac1{51}$$

On base of mutually exclusiveness.